# T-SQL Random Output of Two Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of users that are owned by various Owners. One person left and the list of users needs to be split up between two owners. How would you use SQL to randomly assign the users between two ownerIds . For example, a function that theoretically behaves like below

```
UPDATE Users
set OwnerId = RAND(64,72)
Where OwnerId = 37
```

We are utilizing SQL Server 2012. Tried looking at a random function between two users but is unable to find anything specific. Thank you,

Comment: SQL Server 2012 has been formally end of life since 2019. That means it no longer receives any updates -- **not even critical security patches** -- and hasn't for several years now. Updating to a supported version is job #1 here.

Comment: Something like `case when rand() > 0.5 then 64 else 72 end` may work.

Comment: Do they need to be split evenly If not, then something like the above would work, but if not you *might* end up with one person having significantly more than the other. If that's the case, why not just do something like number all the individuals (with `ROW_NUMBER`, which could be based on `NEW_ID` or even just their surname) and the assign the odd numbers to one person and evens to the other.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn 2019 isn't correct. It ran out of mainstream in 2017, and extended in earlier this year (2022); I think you're thinking of 2008.

Comment: @Arvo That will only work if you update one row at a time.

Comment: @Larnu and Joel Coehoorn    We are currently working on migrating off 2012 as it looks like it reached end of life in July 2022. Hopefully we can get everything out for the end of the year. Thank you so much for the concern and keep putting the message out! I know how important security is but unfortunately don't have much say in when we need to update / change things (barely a year out of college so I still have the Noob aura surrounding me).

Comment: @Arvo Thank you for the assistance! That helped point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CHECKSUM(NEWID())` which returns an integer that is either odd or even, so then just check mod 2 (`% 2`).

```
UPDATE dbo.Users
   SET OwnerId = CASE 
   WHEN CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 2 = 0 THEN 64 ELSE 72 END
WHERE OwnerId = 37;
```

Working example [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BgSycDJd).

If you want to be cryptic/clever or play code golf, then something like this can work *in this very specific example*:

```
UPDATE dbo.Users 
  SET OwnerId = 64 + (CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 2 * 8)
WHERE OwnerId = 37;
```

The reason this works better than `RAND()` is because [`RAND()` is only evaluated once](https://dbfiddle.uk/AIkfLLic), whereas `NEWID()` is evaluated for every row.

Following [Larnu's recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74348348/t-sql-random-output-of-two-values/74348535#comment131255459_74348348), though, you could also do this:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT ID, OwnerId, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID)
  FROM dbo.Users
  WHERE OwnerId = 37
)
UPDATE cte SET OwnerId = 64 + (rn % 2 * 8);
```

Working example [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OZraC1N2). This will produce a more even (but perhaps too predictable) distribution, it just can't be exactly even if there are an odd number of existing matching rows.

Comment: That is perfect! It generated it pretty much evenly across both owners. Thank you so much for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

First let's discuss how to provide example data. One of the better ways is to provide the SQL to define an object and then populate it with data. In your case something like this would use useful:

```
DECLARE @users TABLE (UserID INT, OwnerID INT)
INSERT INTO @users (UserID, OwnerID) VALUES
(1, 100),(2, 100),(3, 100),(4, 100),(5, 100),(6, 100),(7, 100),(8, 100),(9, 100),(10, 100)
```

Now we can use that to provide a demo.
If you truly want to randomly assign between two users, it's a bit more complicated. To divide the users evenly between two new owners you could do something like this

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN UserID % 2 = 0 THEN 101 ELSE 102 END AS NewOwner
  FROM @users
```

All we're doing here is finding the modulo of the UserID to look for it being 0. If the userID can be evenly divided by 2 then Owner 101 gets the user, otherwise Owner 102 gets them.

```
UserID  OwnerID NewOwner
------------------------
1       100     102
2       100     101
3       100     102
4       100     101
5       100     102
6       100     101
7       100     102
8       100     101
9       100     102
10      100     101
```

If you want to split between more users, increase the modulo and provide more WHEN options:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN UserID % 3 = 0 THEN 101 
               WHEN UserID % 3 = 1 THEN 102 
               ELSE 103 END AS NewOwner
  FROM @users
```

```
UserID  OwnerID NewOwner
------------------------
1       100     102
2       100     103
3       100     101
4       100     102
5       100     103
6       100     101
7       100     102
8       100     103
9       100     101
10      100     102
```

To make the split actually random we can leverage the RAND function. This isn't usually random for each row, but we can bully it a bit.

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN (ROUND(((3 - 1 -1) * RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY)) + 1), 0) - 1) = 0 THEN 101 ELSE 102 END AS NewOwner
  FROM @users
```

```
UserID  OwnerID NewOwner
1       100     101
2       100     101
3       100     101
4       100     102
5       100     102
6       100     101
7       100     102
8       100     101
9       100     102
10      100     102
```

We can add additional values like this: (note the extra WHEN and random sequence range increased to 4)

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN (ROUND(((4 - 1 -1) * RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY)) + 1), 0) - 1) = 0 THEN 101
               WHEN (ROUND(((4 - 1 -1) * RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY)) + 1), 0) - 1) = 1 THEN 102
               ELSE 103 END AS NewOwner
  FROM @users
```

```
UserID  OwnerID NewOwner
------------------------
1       100     102
2       100     103
3       100     101
4       100     101
5       100     101
6       100     103
7       100     102
8       100     103
9       100     103
10      100     103
```